# JavaFX Application does not start when JAVA_HOME is set

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, exe, executable

I package my JavaFX Application with java 1.8u45 and Inno5 as an .exe file with the ant. And the executable works when installing it on a computer, where either Java 8 is installed and set as JAVA_HOME environment variable or when no java is installed at all. But if e.g. java 1.6 or less is installed and the JAVA_HOME variable is set to java 1.6 the application will not start with the very generic error `Failed to start jvm`. Starting the bundled .jar file via `java -jar foobar.jar` either causes a failure and stops jvm entirely or prints `unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.

How can I tell JavaFX to never use JAVA_HOME?

The application is packaged as an exe with the fxbuilder, using:

```
    <fx:deploy verbose="true" embedJNLP="false" extension="false" includeDT="false" offlineAllowed="true" outdir="${basedir}/target/deploy" outfile="application" nativeBundles="exe" updatemode="background">
        <!-- To list all classes loaded -->
        <!--<fx:jvmarg value="-verbose:class"/>

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}" />-->
        <fx:info title="App" vendor="Me" />

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication" />
        <fx:resources refid="appRes" />
    </fx:deploy>
```

Comment: Please elaborate how do you package an app? Did you use fxpackager, with that parameters?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev yes I use the fxpackager and updated the quesion with more detail information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When having bundled with the JRE, the native launcher looks up for the filename corresponding `.cfg`-file, which contains the information about the JRE-location (there should be some line like this: `app.runtime=$APPDIR\runtime`)

If that `.cfg`-file only contains `app.runtime=`(without the value), the native launcher does search for local installed JREs:
https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/blob/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/native/library/common/Package.cpp#L120

On windows, the native launcher checks inside the system-registry and does NOT check for JAVA_HOME-property!
https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/blob/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/native/library/common/WindowsPlatform.cpp#L188

The same goes for other platforms, but they are checking for JRE_HOME, but never JAVA_HOME.

I would suggest you to check the windows-registry (was JDK 6 installed AFTER a JDK 8 which replaced the higher-version?)!

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin and creator of the javafx-gradle-plugin.

Comment: JDK or JRE 6 was installed after JRE 8. Is there any way to force the exe to use the JRE set in `app.runtime`? Why is JavaFX even looking for java in the registry and JRE_HOME, when it is packaged as part of the executable?

Comment: I have double-checked the sources, the System-JRE is only used when `app.runtime`-field has no value. See for yourself: https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/blob/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/native/library/common/Package.cpp#L116

Comment: @Huber I just saw that you are trying to run your application via `java`-executable, and not via native launcher! Have you tried to use the full-qualified path to java.exe? Something like `c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe -jar foobar.jar` ... the first java being found on the PATH will be taken if no full path was given

Comment: But starting the application with `foobar.exe` causes it to throw the `Failed to start JVM error`. I don't know what causes this error message, as `app.runtime` is set. Something of JavaFX seems to reference to something that's part of the system, like a registry entry or environment variable.

Comment: Just make sure you have bundled the application correct, maybe your application is crashing somehow. First check via `java -jar` (with absolute path), then check executing the exe-file, and then check installing it locally too (everything on the developer-system). As I checked and said, it only uses that SystemJRE when not having it's bundled JRE being set.